# Where the method looks undefined in nestjs interface

Tags: typescript, nestjs

When I see following code,

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/packages/common

For example `ArgumentsHost` was defined by interface.

But it seems the contents of methods are not defined.

```
 * @publicApi
 */
export interface ArgumentsHost {
  /**
   * Returns the array of arguments being passed to the handler.
   */
  getArgs<T extends Array<any> = any[]>(): T;
  /**
   * Returns a particular argument by index.
   * @param index index of argument to retrieve
   */
  getArgByIndex<T = any>(index: number): T;
  /**
   * Switch context to RPC.
   * @returns interface with methods to retrieve RPC arguments
   */
  switchToRpc(): RpcArgumentsHost;
  /**
   * Switch context to HTTP.
   * @returns interface with methods to retrieve HTTP arguments
   */
  switchToHttp(): HttpArgumentsHost;
  /**
   * Switch context to WebSockets.
   * @returns interface with methods to retrieve WebSockets arguments
   */
  switchToWs(): WsArgumentsHost;
  /**
   * Returns the current execution context type (string)
   */
  getType<TContext extends string = ContextType>(): TContext;
}
```

But when I see following instruction,

https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

`ArgumentsHost` was used and `switchToHttp()` works well.

Why these methods work without specific definitions ?

Do I miss big issue ? As I am beginner, if someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost, HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const status = exception.getStatus();

    response
      .status(status)
      .json({
        statusCode: status,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        path: request.url,
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually not specific to Nest, but to TypeScript (and other languages) in general.
The interface defines a type, and your `catch` method specifies that its second argument must be some value that has that type.
What this means is that any value that has the right "shape" can be used as the second argument.

It turns out that the Nest library itself is responsible for providing a value to your defined `catch` method, and when it does, it must provide a concrete "instance" of the `ArgumentsHost` interface.
As an example of such an instance, see the definition of [`ExecutionContextHost`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/c1bb979d174b28f3ab78c87edae507beb19bbc0f/packages/core/helpers/execution-context-host.ts).
(as it turns out, `ExecutionContextHost` actually implements a *different* interface, `ExecutionContext`, but `ExecutionContext` *extends* `ArgumentsHost`, so it is a valid instance).

This is a very general and powerful technique for writing functions that only require that their inputs have a certain "shape", that is, certain properties or methods.

As an example, imagine writing a graphics library with a `render` function that takes an array of objects representing shapes as input and draws them to the screen.
What type should these shapes have?
We probably want to allow for many kinds of shapes (like squares, circles, or even more exotic things), and these shapes might be very different.
However, as long as each shape knows how to draw itself, then we can write our `render` function like this:

```
function render(shapes: Drawable[]) {
  shapes.forEach(shape => shape.draw());
}

interface Drawable {
  draw: () => void;
}
```

As a result, any object that has a suitable `draw` method can be passed as part of the array of arguments to `render`, *regardless* of whatever else it contains.

To return to your question, the `draw` method isn't *defined* by the `Drawable` interface; instead, the `Drawable` interface is a way of constraining other types: it's like a kind of sieve that only allows certain things through.

The `draw` method is defined by concrete *instances* of the interface.
For example:

```
class Square extends Drawable {
  public x: number;
  public y: number;
  public sideLength: number;

  draw() {
    // Drawing logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I understood ! so the code in question,  `host.switchTohttp()` . it refere to `ExecutionContextHost` ? but How can I locate `ExecutionContextHost` ?  I coudn't find `ExecutionContextHost` just by reading `ArgumentsHost` code.

Comment: Excellent! In general, I don't know of any surefire way to find instances of a particular type, but here is a strategy that works pretty well if you have access to the source. The first thing I'd try is searching for `"implements ArgumentsHost"` (the quotes are important if you're searching in a GitHub repo). This will return any classes that directly implement the interface. No results, as we expect. Next, we can find any interface that _extends_ `ArgumentsHost` by searching for `"extends ArgumentsHost"`. Here we find that `ExecutionContext` does.

Comment: Then we repeat, this time searching for `"implements ExecutionContext"`. Finally we've found an instance! This search shows us that `ExecutionContextHost` implements the `ExecutionContext` interface. So (at least as far as I know), it involves a bit of "rummaging around".